# Japanese onomatopoeia for shattering glass?

Tags: manga, onomatopoeia

I'm seeing both ガシャーン/ガシャン and just ガシャ. Are either of these correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes both are correct. ガシャ sounds shorter, and ガシャーン sounds longer, like the sound resonated in the room. Another common option is パリン/パリーン (sounds lighter or more high-pitched than ガシャン).

- [Typical ガシャーン from Pixta](https://pixta.jp/audio/71195636)
- [Typical パリーン from Pixta](https://pixta.jp/audio/85097448)